# Distinct by 2 columns Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have list from a view which needs to filter displayed data by `App_Id` & `Job_Id`

```
ReturnDbForTesEntities1 db = new ReturnDbForTesEntities1();
List<VapplicantData> list = new List<VapplicantData>();
list = db.VapplicantData.ToList();
```

How can I make this "distinct by 2 columns"?

Comment: db.VapplicantData.Select(x => new { x.col1, x.col2 }).Distinct();

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list to 'system.collections.generic.list @BenRobinson

Comment: list = db.VapplicantData.Select(x => new { x.App_id, x.job_id  }).Distinct().ToList ();

Comment: @PaulZahra What do you base this on? In EF the query will be executed in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use a groupby instead of a distinct, that way you can get a list of `VapplicantData`.

```
List<VapplicantData> list = db.VapplicantData.GroupBy(p => new {p.App_Id, p.Job_Id})
                                             .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                             .ToList()
```

Comment: its get repeated data (App_id and Job_Id) repeated !

Comment: Additional information: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead. and when using FirstorDefault Get repeated data  !

Comment: although data not repeated in database it repeat the row :D

Comment: Post the table contents and the output of that method for comparison.
Also if you if the appId - jobId combination in the system is supposed to be unique, I would add a unique key index to the database table, preventing incorrect data being entered.